# The [course-discovery] repo is already checked out ERROR

Tags: edx, openedx

I'm trying to start with EDX using this [docs](https://github.com/edx/devstack/blob/master/README.rst#getting-started).

When I try to `make dev.clone` or `make dev.provision` I got such error

```
The [course-discovery] repo is already checked out. Checking for updates.
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'dev.clone' failed
```

What's wrong? And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have cloned the repository in the wrong way.

To start working on [edx devstack](https://github.com/edx/devstack), you need to create folder and do `git clone` there. Then `cd devstack` and follow [instruction](https://github.com/edx/devstack#getting-started).

Hope, that will help somebody, who is starting open edx